# after importing '.h' into the '.m' file, are they FOREVER linked?

Tags: objective-c, header, implementation

I have a `CarClass.h` file that declares `CarClass`.
I then `#import` this `CarClass.h` file into my `CarClass.m` file where I of course then go on to implement all my `CarClass` methods.
Finally, my `CarAPP.m` file (which contains the `main`) ALSO `#imports` `CarClass.h` - and everything works just fine.

Ss there are actually no problems there :-)

However, I'm not sure I understand WHY it works - cause the linkage seems a little off: if   `CarAPP.m` imports ONLY the `CarClass.h` file - without also importing the `CarClass.m` file, then where does it GET or SEE the implementations from?
Is it the case that once the ".m" file - which imports the ".h" file - is compiled, then the two files (.h and .m) are sorta forever linked or something?
I just don't get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiling process is split in different phases, and `#import` directives are interpreted long before any linkage occurs.

When you give code files (.c, .m) to your compiler, it will try to generate a code object file (.o) from it; that is, a binary representation of your code. This file is not yet executable because it needs more information. Especially, it's not linked to any other file. Header files, supposed to contain only declarations and no definition, typically don't get their own matching .o file.

After all your code files have been made into code objects, the compiler will put them all together and invoke the linker. The linker will resolve all external references, and then will produce an executable file.

The point is that header files tell the compiler that a function or method *exists somewhere*. This is enough at the current phase of compilation to produce object files: the compiler just needs to be told what exists, not where's the definition. Only when you actually link you need to know this.

Since all your code object files get packaged together, your whole program gets access to everything that was publicly declared within itself. This is why you don't need to explicitly "link" CarAPP.m against CarClass.m.

It's also possible to mislead the compiler and declare functions in header files that not defined anywhere. If you use them in your program, the first phases of compilation will go just fine (no syntax error, no "undeclared function") but it will break at link-time, since the linker won't be able to locate the nonexistent function.

Comment: this definitely sheds more light on the mysterious background-workings of everything - which I know nothing about. Didn't even know there was such a thing called "linker" for example. My excuse for not knowing is that I'm a newbie :-)  Anyway, thank you - Good stuff!

Answer (score 0):

When you have `#import whatEver.h`, the pre-processer tries to finds the corresponding file in the default location. If found, it just pastes the content of the `whatEver.h` to the corresponding source file where ever you use `#import whatEver.h`. So, to get a final executable, your source files should pass Pre-Process, Compile and Linker stages.

When you have `CarClass.h` in `CarAPP.m`, the linker goes to find the implementations of `CarClass.h` in `CarClass.m`. Strictly, speaking it goes to find the definitions in `CarClass.o`. Compiler is happy as long as there are declarations of what you use and the linker is happy as long as there are definitions for the declarations when you intend to use.

When you import `CarClass.h` to your `CarAPP.m`, you are saying to linker to find the `CarClass.h` method implementations in `CarClass.o`. So, your final executable is a combination of `CarAPP.o` and `CarClass.o`. To understand more about how compiling and linking is done, [Program Compilation](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node3.html). Though link is C/C++ specific, it should give you an idea.

Comment: interesting - and good to know. I had no idea about ".o" files.  Sounds like that's the key to understanding the "missing link" in that whole chain. thank you! :-)